# Futuro anteriore nel discorso indiretto

Tags: grammar, verbs

Buongiorno,

ho trovato una regola con le frasi seguenti su [questo sito web](http://www.adgblog.it/2012/01/13/discorso-diretto-%E2%80%93-discorso-indiretto/):

> Esempio:
>
> Disse: “Ti scriverò dopo che sarò ritornato a casa”.
>
> Disse che le avrebbe scritto dopo che fosse ritornato a casa.
>
> Se in una proposizione incontriamo un unico verbo al FUTURO, questo segue la regola del futuro nel passato e diventa CONDIZIONALE COMPOSTO. Se, però, in una proposizione incontriamo due verbi al FUTURO, quello che descrive l’azione precedente (espressa da un futuro anteriore o da un futuro semplice con valore di anteriorità) va al TRAPASSATO CONGIUNTIVO e solo quello che descrive l’azione successiva va al CONDIZIONALE COMPOSTO.

Come si puo spiegare questa regola? Grazie.

Saluti

Irek

Comment: Dove hai trovato la regola? Suggerirei anche di migliorare la formattazione (per esempio con dei ritorni a capo) per facilitare la lettura.

Comment: Questa regola sembrerebbe quella usuale del discorso indiretto, ma in effetti sarebbe utile capire la tua fonte.

Comment: Non capisco questa regola. Qual è la fonte? Ecco un esempio che ho tratto dal libro *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* (Loescher Editore, Torino, 2013). **Discorso diretto:** Disse: "Verrò quando avrò finito". --> **Discorso indiretto:** "Disse che sarebbe venuto quando avrebbe finito".

Comment: @Benedetta: Ma veramente il futuro anteriore va cambiato nel congiuntivo trapassato nel discorso indiretto? Non è così nell'esempio che ho trovato nel mio libro.

Comment: @Charo: aspettiamo di vedere la fonte. Il congiuntivo trapassato potrebbe essere usato per mantenere l'anteriorità. Ho anche io dei dubbi.

Comment: @Charo La frase *Disse che sarebbe venuto quando avrebbe finito* mi suona molto male. Secondo me ci va decisamente il congiuntivo: *Disse che sarebbe venuto quando avesse finito*.

Comment: @Charo Onestamente quasi tutte queste frasi suonano molto più naturali se espresse tramite un modo indefinito: *Disse che sarebbe venuto dopo aver finito*. In ogni caso anch'io preferisco il congiuntivo, ma sarebbe meglio avere una buona fonte "ufficiale" che descrivesse la regola.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Può darsi che abbiate ragione, quindi la risposta a questa domanda interessa anche a me.

Comment: Grazie per la vostra discussione. La fonte e adgblog.it Saluti

Comment: @egreg: Se ne parla [qui](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?p=43547). A quanto pare, per esprimere la funzione del futuro nel passato nel discorso indiretto, è corretto usare sia il congiuntivo trapassato (chiamato anche "congiuntivo piucchepperfetto") sia il condizionale composto. Si menziona un passaggio del libro *Grande Grammatica Italiana di Consultazione* (a cura di L. Renzi, G. Salvi, A. Cardinaletti, Bologna 2001, «Il Mulino», vol. II, § VIII.3.2.3., p. 458). Qualcuno di voi l'ha a portata di mano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao Irek! Vedo che ti piace la grammatica italiana! :)

[image: Regola da descrivere]

Vediamo di usare degli esempi per capire:

SE IN UNA PROPOSIZIONE INCONTRIAMO UN UNICO VERBO AL FUTURO, QUESTO SEGUE LA REGOLA DEL FUTURO NEL PASSATO E DIVENTA CONDIZIONALE COMPOSTO.

La regola che citi si riferisce alla trasformazione del discorso diretto al discorso indiretto.

DISCORSO DIRETTO: Luisa disse: "berrò (verbo al futuro) il caffè appena arrivo in ufficio".

DISCORSO INDIRETTO: Luisa disse che avrebbe bevuto (verbo al condizionale composto) il caffè appena fosse arrivata in ufficio.

- "Condizionale composto" significa "condizionale passato" -

Se, però, in una proposizione incontriamo due verbi al FUTURO, quello che descrive l’azione precedente (espressa da un futuro anteriore o da un futuro semplice con valore di anteriorità) va al TRAPASSATO CONGIUNTIVO e solo quello che descrive l’azione successiva va al CONDIZIONALE COMPOSTO.

DISCORSO DIRETTO: Luisa disse: "Berrò (azione successiva) il caffè dopo che sarò ritornata (azione precedente)a casa".

DISCORSO INDIRETTO: Luisa disse che avrebbe bevuto (condizionale composto o passato) il caffè dopo che fosse ritornata (trapassato congiuntivo) a casa.

"BERE IL CAFFÈ" è l'azione successiva rispetto a "TORNARE A CASA" perché Luisa prima torna a casa e poi beve il caffè.

Comment: Ciao Charo, che differenza c'e tra le due frasi: 1."berrò (verbo al futuro) il caffè appena arrivo in ufficio" e 2."berrò (verbo al futuro) il caffè se arrivo in ufficio". ???Non hanno tutte e due un valore del  primo modo ipotetico? Saluti. Irek.